# Android trying to load a resource that is not declared

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have several crash reports with the following error:

```
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f07010b
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable + 2096(Resources.java:2096)
```

What baffles me is that the app only uses PNG images. There isn't any reference to ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp.xml in the code, only to ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp.png. The error only happens in Android 4.

Does anyone have a clue about what may be causing the error?

Comment: That might be code from a library trying to load a resource from a library.

Comment: I don't think so. The error happens when a layout that does contain the png image is inflated. And only happens in Android 4. I also checked and couldn't find any reference to the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Its likely a library loading it.  Its probably trying to load the icon here:  https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/hardware/drawable-anydpi-v21/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp.xml

If you don't want to find and fix the library, including that file in your build should fix it.